# Backbone memory leaks: always do remove() before render()

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have found a few resources that recommend to explicitly remove a Backbone view before rendering another one in its place.

Is it still the case?  Should I call remove() on the current view, if I want to navigate to another route and render another view?

And while we at at, when I do $('body').html(...) - what happens to the existing content in 'body', does it get removed and garbage collected?

Comment: Yes, you should call `remove`, that's where all the view's cleanup should be. Check the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2) to see what `$('body').html(...)` will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you're doing. But as a good practice, use the `remove()` method from the view is recommended.

If you are using Backbone with jQuery, and you don't have listeners bound to your models/collections you don't need to remove elements before render.

Turns out that if you try to replace a element content using jQuery, the lib will handle the children, data and associate events removing. jQuery's documentation says:

> When `.html()` is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content. Additionally, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from child elements before replacing those elements with the new content.

But if you are binding events between your view and your model/collection, you should do [stopListening](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) from backbone, or this events will be associated in the event stack of your backbone element until you refresh your related models/collections.

By executing the Backbone View [remove](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) method you will execute the jQuery `remove()` and Backbone `stopListening()`.

Comment: spot on.  Thanks very much, just what I wanted to know.  A little strange, though that I saw quite a lot of code which does not do remove(), even though there are listenTo's in the views.

Answer (score 0):

The theoretical logic behind these Views is that they are objects that cannot be garbage collected as long as there is either:

- A reference to the DOM,
- Another object such as a model that is bound to the view and that listens to certain events.

Based on your last comment to the answer of @GabrielGartz:

The reason why you would call jquery's `remove()` is because it will remove the references to the DOM. Afaik, Backbone uses jquery's `on` in order to listen to events related to the view's `el` and its child elements (these events bubble up). jquery's `remove()`clears these DOM listeners.

jQuery docs:

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, **all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed**.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
>   instead.

The DOM reference is unrelated from the Backbone View that as an object would take a model as a property that uses `listenTo`to listen to events that can be broadcasted from other parts of your application.

I hope this helps.